# How to get time value in milliseconds from a date object python?

Tags: python, date, milliseconds

As part of my new work I need to convert one existing java class to a python one.

```
person.setDob(String.valueOf(person.getDateOfBirth().getTime()));
```

Please see the above snippet here how to fetch time in milliseconds from date object in python,
Hope I can use datetime.datetime for this purpose. Please help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

To get a date string with milliseconds (3 decimal places behind seconds), use this:

```
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

> OUTPUT 2018-10-04 10:18:32.926

`%f` is displaying milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

To get milliseconds in python, use the below code.

```
 import datetime
 print('Datetime in milliscond using now()',datetime.datetime.now())
 print('Datetime in milliscond using utcfromtimestamp()', datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0))
```

output looks like below

```
 Datetime in milliscond using now() 2019-03-11 17:34:28.290409
 Datetime in milliscond using now() 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```